# How to start automatically issue a command in one tab of terminal console

Tags: macos, terminal

When I use terminal on OSX, I normally have console terminal open with a number of different tabs. In one of those tabs I have a `localhost` server and in another tab I have a different `localhost` server. I have saved this window configuration as a windows group that is reopened when I restart terminal, say upon rebooting.

When I restart terminal, I want the two tabs with servers in them to restart the servers.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give some more detail on exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have added some more information to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you. Go to Preferences under the Terminal menu and a panel opens. Click on the Profiles icon on the top left of the panel. This opens a new panel as shown below.

[image]

Click on the shell tab at the top of the new panel. The first item, as shown in the image, is where you can define a command or commands to run when the tab is opened.